# LayerUI appears only after blocking method is done

Tags: java, multithreading, paint

I created a little indication of loading using a custom subclass of LayerUI.

The **list** is and **arraylist of StringWorker subclass**. Its **get** method is a blocking call so I assume that's the problem just don't know how to fix it. The layer starts a timer and as far as I know, timers are executed in their own thread so the blocking **get** shouldn't intefere.

```
        loadingLayer.setVisible(true);
        lockComponents();
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("About to check "+i);
                if(list.get(i).get() == null) {

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        unlockComponents();
        loadingLayer.setVisible(false);
```

The "loadingLayer" appears only after all this code is done.

LoadingLayerUI class:

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;
public class LoadingLayerUI extends LayerUI<JComponent> implements ActionListener {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 827885062549399916L;
private boolean isShowing;
private Timer timer;


private String text;


@Override
public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent jc) {
    super.paint(g, jc);
    if(!isShowing) 
        return;

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    int w = jc.getWidth();
    int h = jc.getHeight();
    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
            AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .7f));
    g2.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Font font = new Font("Sans-Serif",Font.BOLD, 20);
    int width = g2.getFontMetrics(font).stringWidth("Loading");
    g2.setFont(font);
    if(text != null) 
        g2.drawString(text, (w-width)/2, h/2);

    g2.dispose();
    jc.repaint();
}

public void setVisible(boolean set) {
    this.isShowing = set;
    if(isShowing) {
        timer = new Timer(200, this);
        timer.start();
    }
    else {
        timer.stop();
    }
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(!isShowing && timer.isRunning())
        timer.stop();

    if(text == null || text.equals("Downloading...")) {
        text = "Downloading";
    }
    else 
        text += ".";

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use Swing you should make your long running tasks in a separate thread.

Here is the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: Okay. I moved the large part to a swing worker. Now I show they layed(it doesn't appear) create,execute and store swing workers in an arraylist. It still does not appear. However, if I show the layer just after I add components to my JFrame, then it shows up.

Comment: @Bebras How you update your layer? Don't forget you should do it in EDT (so either using publish method of swing worker or SwingUtilities.invokeLater.

Comment: Well the **setVisible** method starts a timer which changes a string that is painted. Which part of it should be in EDT?

Comment: @Bebras Timer is ok (if swing Timer). Ok you should try to debug your application. I don't see a clear mistake.

Comment: I don't see a difference between timers but it is imported from the swing package.

Comment: @Bebras Swing timer make ticks in EDT

Answer (score 1):

I moved the code which uses the blocking method **get** to a separate thread and made it call a method when it was done. Now it seems to work. The layer appears and disappears when needed.

```
        loadingLayer.setVisible(true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        if(list.get(i).get() == null) {

                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                downloadComplete();
            }
        }).start();
```

The **downloadComplete** method simply hides the layer.